# Create a password protected excel with asp without excel installed in server

Tags: excel, asp-classic, password-protection

I know there is a method used to create a password protected excel using

```
Set obj_xls = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
```

but it needs to install excel in the server

Is there any other method can be used instead which DO NOT need excel installed in server?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? a more suitable approach can be conceived if you share more of what task you're faced with. This will also help you in asking clearer questions.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I want to created a password protected excel using asp

Comment: Do you have access to WScript.Shell? if so, i would suggest creating a simple CSV file with asp then zip into an encrypted archive using 7zip.exe?

Comment: so other then installing Microsoft excel in the server, there is no other method to create a password-protected excel with asp?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I installed excel in the server to produce my required result..